# SQL Server Random Rows for each column type

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to get 3 different players for thier playerRole column . I am using

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FantasyPlayers WHERE playerRole = 1 ORDER BY NEWID()`

query to get random row for playerRole = 1

However i want to get

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FantasyPlayers WHERE playerRole = 1 ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FantasyPlayers WHERE playerRole = 2 ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM FantasyPlayers WHERE playerRole = 3 ORDER BY NEWID()
```

3 random players with 3 different role which means one 1 random player for each playerRole .

I tried Union which is not returning anything due to NEWID()

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The union should work, what do you mean "not returning anything"? Post your query and exact results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this without a subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties fp.*
from FantasyPlayers fp
order by row_number() over (partition by playerRole order by newid();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps...

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playerRole
                              ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RN
    FROM FantasyPlayers)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```